# Categorize or GroupBy datastream data and process with CEP separately

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing, data-stream

Assume I have a datastream

```
x:1, y:2 , z:3 , x:7 , y:-1, z:0, z:3 , z:2, y:3 ,x: 2 ,y:6
```

How do I put `x,y,z` in their own bucket and apply my CEP rule on it.

```
x:1, x:7,x: 2 
y:2, y:-1, y:3 , y:6
z:3, z:0 , z:3, z:2
```

Or to put it in other way. How do I split the stream in to these categories(one stream for each x,y,z). I would get 3 sub streams which has their own CEP processing.

The challenge here is , the x,y,z are not pre-defined.So I cannot pre-create streams and assign using an if or switch statement.

**Edit:**
The pattern would be like ," if x value is between 0 - 8 for  the last 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is done by "keying" the stream on the category attribute.

If you have a `DataStream[(String, Int)]` this looks a follows:

```
val yourStream: DataStream[(String, Int)] = ???
val yourPattern: Pattern = ???

// key by String attribute
val keyedStream = yourStream.keyBy(_._1) 
// apply pattern on keyed stream 
val patternStream: PatternStream = CEP.pattern(keyedStream, yourPattern)
```

The pattern will be evaluated for each distinct value of the keyed attribute.

Comment: Edited my question. How will I make it work for my requirement. I would have to watch the x value for 10 minutes and take a decision.